# CURL can not run with Domain name on local Server

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to use curl to run a local php file inside my centOs7 shared server, but i can not use curl method for my local files.
here are my example files :

```
--bg/
------back.php
------curl.php
```

here is curl.php codes:

```
<?php
function run_curl($data){
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = '';
    //foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = http_build_query($data);
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: ' . $content_type]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://taskdan.com/bg/back.php');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,50); # timeout after 10 seconds, you can increase it
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  # Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); # Some server may refuse your request if you dont pass user agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //print_r($result);
    //print_r((curl_getinfo($ch)));
    //error_log($result);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return ($result); 
}
echo " Output : </br>";
echo run_curl( [
    "ab" => "test"
]);
?>
```

and the below my back.php codes:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
echo json_encode([
    "a" => "test"
])
?>
```

When I run this code, it looks like it converts my domain name to the server's public  IP address. Curl is working fine for outside of server scripts.

when i run curl with using SSH, i get this:

```
[root@??? ~]# curl https://taskdan.com -k
<html>Apache is functioning normally</html>
[root@??? ~]# curl http://171.22.27.118 -k
<html>Apache is functioning normally</html>
```

i want to run some scripts in background, Are there any way to run a local php file with POST parameters by CURL?

Comment: I don't think all those line breaks and spaces are valid JSON. Also, your function returns the json decoded info but doesn't do anything with it. For debugging, change your function to return the raw results, and use `echo run_curl(...)` instead

Comment: @Stevish, hi i change my code as you see in question, but it does not work and i got 404 error. how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to talk to your hosting provider? This doesn't feel like a problem with your code but with the server setup. And if you're in a shared hosting environment it's not likely you have a lot of control over the server configuration.

Comment: @Stevish , no , i have shared Server with Centos and DA

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your use of "Shared Server" in your original post. I'm unfamiliar with DirectAdmin, but it sounds like Miken32 has your solution if you're willing to try it.

Comment: Do not switch `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` off. It creates a security flaw.

Comment: @Dharman, i do this too, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your Apache virtual host is configured for listening on all interfaces?
When you do a DNS lookup to a domain that is configured as 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts the request is then pointed to the loopback interface.
Open your virtualhost configuration and search for:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
```

If it is configured as

```
<VirtualHost 171.22.27.118:80>
```

Change it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

..and try again

If you cannot edit the VirtualHost definition for any reason you can instruct cURL to make the request on a specific address/port and set the correct Host header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Host: taskdan.com'
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://171.22.27.118/bg/back.php');
```

This could help mitigate the issue but is not guaranteed to work as the problem is the webserver configuration not the source code per se.

Comment: hi , thanks for answering, yes is see many of `<VirtualHost 171.22.27.118:80>` in `Contents of the httpd.conf file for taskdan.com` into my DirectAdmin, but i can not change it because it does not have any Save button? how can i change it?

Comment: @Stevish , i have a CentOS server with DirectAdmin, i have all of access

Comment: can you help me? i really need help to how to change VirtualHost as you say on my srver.

Comment: I don't know how to change the VirtualHost directive in DirectAdmin, seems that the configuration files are generated from a template that you need to modify; have a look at: https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=45557

Comment: i found `/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/taskdan/httpd.conf` file on my server and i edit it as you sad. now it works fine. looks like your new answer about setting host is better. thank you so mmuch

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/hosts` file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Change it to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 taskdan.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 taskdan.com
```

---

Or, just change your code.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://127.0.0.1/bg/back.php');
```

And configure Apache accordingly.

Comment: hi , i change it, but it still does not work.https://taskdan.com/bg/curl.php
i have this also in below of hosts  : 136.243.199.229         taskdan.com

Comment: Well get rid of that then.

Comment: is it safe ? maybe it connects my domain to my host?!

Comment: That's the hostname of your computer; your computer will always be able to find itself at 127.0.0.1

Comment: in nano editor i see: 
 # Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 taskdan.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 taskdan.com

136.243.199.229         taskdan.com

Comment: Might be cached, give your server a restart.

Comment: ,thanks for your time , i restart it , still not working. i use `http://127.0.0.1` as you say but still nut working. :(